# Reason of mono-io-layer-error (10013)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

I am creating a chat application for my android application using XAMARIN but when i am going to start tcp listener then i am getting mono-io-layer-error (10013). Internet option is already selected for permission.

I am calling this inside OnCreate() method of main Activity.

my code is something like this:

```
private void CreateListener()
    {
        HttpListener listener = null;
        HttpListenerContext context = null;
        HttpListenerRequest request = null;
        HttpListenerResponse response = null;
        string PortNumber = "8080";
        string requestUrl;
        Boolean listen = false;

        try
        {
            if (listener == null)
            {
                listener = new HttpListener();
                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.20.93" + PortNumber + "/");
                listener.Start();
                listen = true;
                while (listen)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        context = listener.GetContext();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        listen = false;
                    }
                    if (listen)
                    {
                        request = context.Request;
                        requestUrl = request.Url.ToString();

                        // Process request and/or request Url
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your string which is added to `Prefixes` is wrong.

A URI prefix string is composed of a scheme (http or https), a host, an optional port, and an optional path, for example: `http://www.contoso.com:8080/customerData/`.

Try to change your code `listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.20.93" + PortNumber + "/");` to `listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.20.93:" + PortNumber + "/");`.